# Trying to use pdfcomment’s \pdfmarkupcomment with acro

Tags: errors, pdfcomment, acro

I’ve been trying to use `\pdfmarkupcomment` from the `pdfcomment` package as the `tooltip-cmd` for the `acro` package.
However, I’m getting an error and don’t quite understand where it’s coming from.
The following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[american]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}
% This doesn’t work:
%\usepackage[tooltip-cmd=\pdftooltip]{acro}
\usepackage{acro}

\newcommand{\mytooltip}[2]{\pdfmarkupcomment[opacity=0]{#1}{#2}}
\acsetup{tooltip-cmd=\mytooltip}
\DeclareAcronym{test}{short=test-short, long=test-long}

\begin{document}
    \ac{test}
\end{document}
```

produces the following error:

> ```
> ! Argument of \use:c has an extra }.
> <inserted text> 
>                 \par 
> l.16  \ac{test}
> ```

With `\acsetup{tooltip-cmd=\pdftooltip}` instead, everything works OK.
(As you can see, I’m using `\acsetup` instead of package options such as `\usepackage[tooltip-cmd=\...]{acro}` because that doesn’t work at all, even with `\pdftooltip`.
Shouldn’t both ways work?)

Since `\pdftooltip` works, I’m assuming `\pdfmarkupcomment` is different somehow.
Is there a way to fix this?

I’m using TeX Live 2016/Linux and the problem is with either pdfLaTeX/LuaLaTeX.

Comment: The first mandatory argument of `\pdfmarkupcomment` seems to be passed on to a command from the `soul` package which seems to be the problem here… acro does not pass the pure string to the tooltip command but something like `\use:c {acro_write_short:nv}{test}{l__acro_short_tl}\acro_endings:nn {test}{short}`. The `soul` command doesn't seem to be able to handle this input…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works now with an up to date `acro` (it needs several compilation runs):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage{acro}

\acsetup{
  pdfcomments/use = true ,
  pdfcomments/cmd = {\pdfmarkupcomment[opacity=0]{#1}{#2}}
}

\DeclareAcronym{test}{
  short=test-short,
  long=test-long,
  pdfcomment=test-comment
}

\begin{document}

\ac{test} \pdfmarkupcomment[opacity=0]{bla}{blub}

\end{document}
```

[image]